# Meteor define ReactiveVar to be accesible in .events and .helpers

Tags: meteor

I am trying to define a new ReactiveVar variable to be accessible in all the template sections (ex. .events, .helpers, .rendered ...etc) as shown in my code below, yet I am always getting an error:

```
Error: Exception in template helper:
ReferenceError: logData is not defined
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here? Thanks

Code:

```
  Template.detailedreport.rendered = function() {

       var logData = new ReactiveVar;
       logData.set([]);
  };


  Template.detailedreport.helpers({
      myCollection: function () {
        return logData.get();
      }
  });

  Template.detailedreport.events({
     'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var now  = Session.get("startDate");
        var then = Session.get("endDate");
        var custID = Session.get("customer");
        var projID = Session.get("project");
        Meteor.call('logSummary', now, then, projID, custID, function(error, data){
          if(error)
            return alert(error.reason);

          logData.set(data);
        });
     }  
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the `ReactiveVar` on the template instance like this :

```
Template.detailedreport.created = function() {
  this.logData = new ReactiveVar([]);
};
```

Then you'll be able to access it in helpers like this :

```
Template.detailedreport.helpers({
  myCollection: function () {
    return Template.instance().logData.get();
  }
});
```

In events you can use the `template` argument :

```
Template.detailedreport.events({
  'submit form': function(e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var now  = Session.get("startDate");
    var then = Session.get("endDate");
    var custID = Session.get("customer");
    var projID = Session.get("project");
    Meteor.call('logSummary', now, then, projID, custID, function(error, data){
      if(error){
        return alert(error.reason);
      }
      template.logData.set(data);
    });
  }  
});
```